# How to install Arial for XeLaTeX on Debian 10?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm trying to use XeLaTeX to generate a document that uses the font "Arial".

I have tried this both on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS (where it works) and Debian 10.8 where Arial is missing. On both systems I used `sudo apt install texlive-full` to install LaTeX and am using the command `xelatex document.tex` to generate the pdf.

How can I install Arial on Debian? Or can I move the Arial font files
from the Ubuntu machine to make it work? (I located the fonts in `/usr/share/fonts/windowsfonts` on the Ubuntu machine)

Comment: Arial is a Microsoft proprietary font. Obviously it's not included in TeXlive, or by Debian by default, though [there are ways of installing them in Debian](https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-microsoft-fonts-on-debian-11-bullseye/). However, if you can, I strongly encourage you to use one of the many Free License fonts that are similar: (GNU) FreeSans, Liberation Sans, (URW) Nimbus Sans, TeX Gyre Heros and Arimo all come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the best solution.
But at least it works.

Copying the `arial*.ttf` files from the Ubuntu 20.4 machine in `/usr/share/fonts/windowsfonts` to the same location on the Debian machine allows xelatex to use then.

Note that it's OK that a /windowsfonts folder did not exist before and that sudo rights are needed to write into the /fonts folder.

Comment: To use the Arial font is not good idea. It has proprietary license. No all users accept such license. So, your source document cannot be processed at all computers.

Comment: @wipet It depends on the use case. In this one I'm trying to move away a process currently running on windows to Linux and one of the requirements is that the results stay identical. So here the user *demanded* to use the same fonts...  Of course it's always nicer to avoid proprietary software, but it's not always the best solution.

Comment: Have you verified that the license of the font Arial allows you to copy `ttf` file from one machine to another without newly accepting the license? Probably not. And we can avoid such problems when we are using only free software.